# Upload File with OpenCMIS has no content

Tags: java, file-upload, alfresco, opencmis

I'm trying to upload a file into my Alfresco repository using Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS.
The file is created and the properties are correct but there is no content, the file is 0 bytes. I've double checked and there is nothing wrong with the source file.
Here's my Java code:

```
File content = new File(somepath);
try{
                    String mimeType = new  MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(content);
                    logger.debug("mimetype: " + mimeType);
                    logger.debug("file: " + content.getAbsolutePath());
                    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT.value());
                    properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, content.getName());


                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(content);
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) content.length()];
                    dis.readFully(bytes);

                    ContentStream cs = new ContentStreamImpl(content.getName(), BigInteger.valueOf(bytes.length), mimeType, dis);
                    Folder folder = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath("/myfolder");
                    Document doc = folder.createDocument(properties, cs, VersioningState.MAJOR);
                    return doc.getId();
                }catch(CmisBaseException e){
                    logger.error("error uploading file: "+ e.getMessage(), e);
                }
```

There is no exception catched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is problem with the content stream you are passing.

Try to replace you code with this

```
String docText = "This is a sample document";
byte[] content = docText.getBytes();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
ContentStream contentStream = getSession().getObjectFactory().createContentStream(filename, Long.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);
```

You can gradually change this simple text with content from your new file in next step.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an example about this, and found your question,
the problem with the original if I am not mistaken is that you are
reading the buffer beforehand so the pointer is at the end of it when
you pass it to the content stream, I am making a little class just to test
some functionality I want to implement in a program later and this block 
works with your initial approach.

```
File content = new File("C:\\\\asdf.asdf");
    try{
        String mimeType = new  MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(content);
        System.out.println("mimetype: " + mimeType);
        System.out.println("file: " + content.getAbsolutePath());
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID,BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT.value()+",P:cm:titled");
        properties.put("cm:description", "upload desde código");
        properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, content.getName());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(content); 
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);                    
        ContentStream cs = new ContentStreamImpl(content.getName(),BigInteger.valueOf(content.length()), mimeType, dis);
        Document doc = newFolder.createDocument(properties, cs, VersioningState.MAJOR);
    }catch(CmisBaseException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(CMISTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CMISTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CMISTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```